# Writing a script from an excel file

Tags: excel, oracle, import

I have been given an excel file of around 6000 rows, I am needing to write a script to update an oracle table from it, the query is pretty simple:

```
="update table set phone_number = "&B2&" where entityid = "&D2&";"
```

My question is about the script itself, what is the standard practice for writing a script from a file this size? am i expected to just write a .sql file with 6000 update statements? or is it better to import into oracle by converting the file into a .csv or some other method?

Comment: I can't answer this directly because the syntax will be a bit different but have just had to do the same thing in SQL server and the basic idea is to import the excel file into a new table, then set up a query which joins it to the existing table (inner join) then update only the matching records.

Comment: I'd say you need write a script that will go throw all lines in your xls and update the table (it looks like just one update stamements with parameters inside foreach loop). it can be performance issue if you have hundred of thousands records, but for 6000 I suppose the simple solution should be ok

Comment: ok @are- are you talking about doing a select * from  OPENROWSET

Comment: it's a general approach... I don't know where you are going to implement the logic... it can be inside xls document via VBA, or an external application that has access to both xls and oracle, or it can be oracle storage procedure that has access to the document... in each case the simple logic is as I described... the benefits of this - simple, easy to implement and easy to get first working prototype, the problems of the approach - it can be performance issue on big amount of data because you need call update statement 6000 times...

Answer (score 0):

You could do it easily in **SQL Developer**.

1. Expand the **connection** on the left pane.
2. Expand the **Tables**.
3. Right click on the table, and select **Import Data**

[image]

4. It will open the **Data Import Wizard**.
5. Select your **file** and few more steps before your **import** starts.

If you have a **CSV** file, other options are:

- **SQL Loader** (client side)
- **External Table** (server side).

But if you are not familiar with other options, then go with the **SQL Developer Import option**, easy and **GUI based**.

Comment: I am moving this into production and do not have access to gui, is there a way to do this from the server side?

Comment: you can create pl/sql procedure that will parse the xls and make the updates. see sample here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_load_excel_spreadsheet_into_oracle_table.htm

Comment: @rtd353 On the server you can **create an external table**, convert the excel into csv and then use the file location to insert the data into the external table. Once you have the data in the external table, you can issue direct SQL on it like a normal table to move data into your production table.